# Is it possible to call Pubsub's subscription pull directly in javascript instead of calling java method to fetch the data?

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been working in pubsub where I can successfully pull the data from a particular topic under a particular project in java. If I've to show these data in html, first I've to call the servlet method, then the servlet will call pubsub api to get the data, then I've to include that data in the response.

Since it involves an additional one layer (java) to access the data, is it possible to directly fecth the data in javascript call by skipping the java call..? Is there any api's available in google pubsub to serve for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api can be used in javascript (with ajax) since its just https calls,
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/ 
however its a bad idea because you would need to expose your server account access token and the client could then abuse it.

Comment: Yes I'm too afraid of it. The only way I'm communicating with java and google is with the service account, and doing authentication with other google accounts will not allow me to publish or pull a message from pubsub. I thought of getting the access token for service account via java side and then giving that access token to the client (probably it'll be stored in a varibale in javascript), then making ajax call directly to the url you specified with the Authorization header as that access token. Is that too insecure? Will that also compromise my security.?

Comment: What you describe is exactly what i said you could do and i explained why it would be very insecure. to understand oauth2 read the official guides from google and experiment with it from the "google oauth2 playground". Its very important to understand the process ao you know why you should never expose your token to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your brief explanation. I'll go through oauth2 docs regarding security, but I decided to implement in server side rather than compromising the securtiy in Client side.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks Zig.
Also, as of May 1, 2015, there are limits for number of topics/subscriptions, which are 10,000 topics per project and 10,000 subscriptions per topic. 

Please think Cloud Pub/Sub as a server-to-server communication tool.